# Does Valgrind provide options to capture object's access by function specifically for C++? If so what is the option to be used?

Tags: c++, profiling, valgrind

I would like to know Valgrind provide options to capture object's access by function for a code in C++. Is there any way to capture the objects reads and writes through valgrind?

Comment: you can try callgrind: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.options.collection